# RMarkdown: Table of contents and automatic numbering after# while using cleanrmd theme

Tags: r-markdown, themes, tableofcontents

the theme water-dark from the package cleanrmd is really nice. But I cannot get the toc and automatic numbering to work. It seems like the theme overwrites them somehow. Is there a way to get the "base" function of toc and automatic numbering back while still using the package cleanrmd? My RMarkdown looks like this atm:

```
output:
  cleanrmd::html_document_clean:
    theme: water-dark
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: true
    number_sections_depth: 3
    pandoc_args: ["-V", "classoption=fullwidth"]  
bibliography: references.bib
```

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
body {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  font-size: 12pt;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin 0 auto;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none ;
  color: white;
  
}
 a:focus, a:hover {
  text-decoration: none ;
  color: grey;
}
```
````

I tried to make the toc somewhat ok looking with css, but its note realy the same. All the toc commands do not seem to work, exept the Toc: true.

I tried looking at the css in the html, but I have no idea what I am doing.